# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I hate to ask this question but I have searched and searched and done all sorts of things to see if I can resolve on my own.

Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

var_dump = bool(false)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO resetPswd (userID,key,date,status) VALUES (?,?,NOW(),0)");

$stmt->bind_param('is', $userID,$key);

$stmt->execute();
```

I have removed everything then added all back the problem lies with "key", it works until I add that in.

I am creating a random 'key':

```
 $key = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
```

db = key - varchar(12)

Any help would be great!
Why am I using mysqli? It's required.

Comment: Try with backticles in tablename and column names

Answer (score 4):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

You must escape it with backticks in order to use it as column name.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO resetPswd (userID,`key`,date,status)  
                          VALUES (?,?,NOW(),0)");
```

Comment: Thank You! I knew I was doing something stupid!

Comment: You're welcome @harkly

Comment: `status` and `date` are also in the list of reserved keywords, although MySQL doesn't seem to be strict/consistent when it comes to the `status` keyword

Comment: those are just keywords, the reserved ones have an (R) next to them

Comment: @AlexAndrei exactly ^ ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you only have to tell me once :)

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the call to $mysqli->prepare returned something that isn't an object, my guess would be it returns something like "false" which is not an object and thus you can't call "bind_param" on false. Doesn't sound like $key has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation:

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement,
>   PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server
>   cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns
>   FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-returnvalues

You have an error in your query. `key` is a reserved word and will make that statement return `false`

Comment: Probably best quote something similar from the `mysqli::prepare` documentation